# Loading color map from TXT file into raster layer using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis, symbology, color

I need to configure a pseudocolour symbology of a raster image using a colour map file in txt format using PyQGIS, how can I do it, and what class allows me to access this configuration?

This can be done manually with the buttons located at the bottom of the Layer Properties, in the pseudocolour symbology settings. The buttons highlighted in the image

[image]

The text file with the symbology that is generated and can be loaded by QGIS has the following content:

##Archivo de exportación de mapa de colores generado por QGIS
INTERPOLATION:INTERPOLATED
0.11247780174017,215,25,28,255,0,1125
0.32547278888523601,253,174,97,255,0,3255
0.53846777603030205,255,255,192,255,0,5385
0.75146276317536798,166,217,106,255,0,7515
0.96445775032043501,26,150,65,255,0,9645

Comment: Could you add an example of the contents of such txt file?

Comment: Yes @bugmenot123 I added it to the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a useful method `QgsRasterRendererUtils.parseColorMapFile` you can open your text file and retrieve the shader items for your raster.

```py
import os

from qgis.core import (
    QgsColorRampShader,
    QgsRasterRendererUtils,
    QgsRasterShader,
    QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer
)

os.chdir("/your/folder/with/text/file/")
lyr = iface.activeLayer()  # your raster layer
colormapfile_name = "colormap.txt"

loading, ramp_shader_items, shader_type, errors = QgsRasterRendererUtils.parseColorMapFile(colormapfile_name)

if not loading:
    raise OSError(", ".join(errors))

shader = QgsRasterShader()
ramp_shader = QgsColorRampShader()
ramp_shader.setColorRampType(shader_type)
ramp_shader.setColorRampItemList(ramp_shader_items)
shader.setRasterShaderFunction(ramp_shader)

band = 1
renderer = QgsSingleBandPseudoColorRenderer(
    input=lyr.dataProvider(),
    band=band,
    shader=shader
)
lyr.setRenderer(renderer)
iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

---

*Documentation* : [QgsRasterRendererUtils](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterRendererUtils.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!
However, there is still a problem, it is an old bug, the raster layer symbology is not updated in the layer properties window. I will raise it as a next question